# How to assign UtcNow to a DateTime picker value property?

Tags: c#, razor, model-view-controller, twitter-bootstrap-3, datetimepicker

I'm using the Bootstrap 3 DateTime picker [from here.](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) On load of the Razr form I want to set the default time as the current UtcNow time stamp.

I've tried a number of different DateTime formats in order to set this default. But the control doesn't seem to accept the formats passed in.

Some of the formats tried:

```
//Format #1
DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmtt");

//Format #2
string.Format("{0:g}", DateTime.UtcNow);
```

I know that the format used by the DateTime picker when selecting a time is as follows, `07/13/2016 2:43 AM`, so I think if I can convert the UTC time to this format it will accept the time stamp.

I verified that I can assign this value to a regular input element with the same Razr syntax, so that rules out an issue with the value not being passed over.

**Question:**

How can you assign UtcNow to a DateTime picker default value property?

Controller: In the controller I pass in the `string.Format("{0:g}", DateTime.UtcNow);` as a model property.

```
//Create a dynamic object to store list of different model types.
dynamic dynamicEscalationModel = new ExpandoObject();
dynamicEscalationModel.OutageStartTime = string.Format("{0:g}", DateTime.UtcNow);
```

View: I then use a `@` symbol to assign this value to the DateTime picker:

```
<!-- Outage Start -->
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-9 control-label" style="text-align: left;" for="OutageStartDisplay">Outage Start (*UTC)</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class='input-group date' id='OutageStartDisplay'>
            <input type='text' class="form-control" id="OutageStartDisplayInput" name="OutageStartDisplayInput" value="@Model.OutageStartTime" />
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="OutageStartDisplayCalendar">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For testing I added a second normal input and the model property is bound correctly:

```
<input type='text' class="form-control" id="" name="" value="@Model.OutageStartTime" />
```

The DateTimepicker init in my script tag:

```
//Init the Outage Start date time picker
$(function () {
    $('#OutageStartDisplay').datetimepicker({
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are getting the UTC now, why not do it from client side directly:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var t = new Date(); 
            t.setMinutes(t.getMinutes() + t.getTimezoneOffset());

            $('#OutageStartDisplay').datetimepicker({
                defaultDate: t,
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: I've tried new Date().getTime() and it gives me the local time zone not the UTC. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to a script tag You need to initalize it there:

```
      $('#OutageStartDisplay').datetimepicker({
        format: 'm/d/Y H:i:s',
        theme: 'dark',
        startDate: '@Model.OutageStartTime'
    });
```

Comment: Adding the format and startDate breaks the picker as it can't be selected from but the DateTime is set. The console error is: "bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: option startDate is not recognized"